# Spark Dataset - "edit" parquet file for each row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

#### Context

I am trying to use Spark/Scala in order to "edit" multiple parquet files (potentially 50k+) efficiently. The only edit that needs to be done is deletion (i.e. deleting records/rows) based on a given set of row IDs.

The parquet files are stored in s3 as a partitioned DataFrame where an example partition looks like this:

```
s3://mybucket/transformed/year=2021/month=11/day=02/*.snappy.parquet
```

Each partition can have upwards of 100 parquet files that each are between 50mb and 500mb in size.

#### Inputs

We are given a spark `Dataset[MyClass]` called `filesToModify` which has 2 columns:

1. `s3path: String` = the complete s3 path to a parquet file in s3 that needs to be edited
2. `ids: Set[String]` = a set of IDs (rows) that need to be deleted in the parquet file located at `s3path`

Example input dataset `filesToModify`:

| s3path | ids |
| --- | --- |
| s3://mybucket/transformed/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-1.snappy.parquet | Set("a", "b") |
| s3://mybucket/transformed/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-2.snappy.parquet | Set("b") |

#### Expected Behaviour

Given `filesToModify` I want to take advantage of parallelism in Spark do the following for each `row`:

1. Load the parquet file located at `row.s3path`
2. Filter so that we exclude any row whose `id` is in the set `row.ids`
3. Count the number of deleted/excluded rows per id in `row.ids` (optional)
4. Save the filtered data back to the same `row.s3path` to overwrite the file
5. Return the number of deleted rows (optional)

#### What I have tried

I have tried using `filesToModify.map(row => deleteIDs(row.s3path, row.ids))` where `deleteIDs` is looks like this:

```java
def deleteIDs(s3path: String, ids: Set[String]): Int = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val data = spark
        .read
        .parquet(s3path)
        .as[DataModel]

    val clean = data
        .filter(not(col("id").isInCollection(ids)))

    // write to a temp directory and then upload to s3 with same
    // prefix as original file to overwrite it
    writeToSingleFile(clean, s3path)

    1 // dummy output for simplicity (otherwise it should correspond to the number of deleted rows)
    }
```

However this leads to `NullPointerException` when executed within the `map` operation. If I execute it alone outside of the `map` block then it works but I can't understand why it doesn't inside it (something to do with lazy evaluation?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a `NullPointerException` because you try to retrieve your spark session from an executor.

It is not explicit, but to perform spark action, your `DeleteIDs` function needs to retrieve active spark session. To do so, it calls method `getActiveSession` from `SparkSession` object. But when called from an executor, this `getActiveSession` method returns `None` as stated in [SparkSession's source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala):

> Returns the default SparkSession that is returned by the builder.
>
> Note: Return None, when calling this function on executors

And thus `NullPointerException` is thrown when your code starts using this `None` spark session.

More generally, you can't recreate a dataset and use spark transformations/actions in transformations of another dataset.

So I see two solutions for your problem:

- either to rewrite `DeleteIDs` function's code without using spark, and modify your parquet files by using [parquet4s](https://mjakubowski84.github.io/parquet4s/) for instance.
- or transform `filesToModify` to a Scala collection and use Scala's `map` instead of Spark's one.

Answer (score 3):

`s3path` and `ids` parameters that are passed to `deleteIDs` are not actually strings and sets respectively. They are instead columns.

In order to operate over these values you can instead create a UDF that accepts columns instead of intrinsic types, or you can collect your dataset if it is small enough so that you can use the values in the `deleteIDs` function directly. The former is likely your best bet if you seek to take advantage of Spark's parallelism.

You can read about UDFs [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs.html)